# The static reference of My Android Launcher Activity become null

Tags: android

In my Android Application, I store the Launcher activity (called MainActivity) in a static variable inside the MainActivity class; 
And I am using this static Activity reference to get the application resource, preference and others;

But sometimes, I found that the app is crashed because the object reference is null;

1. Is there any reason causing the object reference become NULL?
2. How to prevent this kind of NullPointerException?

**My Codes:**

*MainActivity:*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static MainActivity sInstance = null;

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       sInstance = this;
       // other code
   }
}
```

*Helper.java*:

```
public static int getColor(int resID) {
    return MainActivity.getInstance().getColor(resID);
}
```

Comment: You should learn the life cycle of Activity and use `Context` to do what you want

Comment: In this case if your activity is destroyed how do you make sure the instance is not null , the approach you are following is wrong . you cant keep a static reference of a activity

Answer (score 1):

```
//For this type of issue, please use application class object. If you used Activity class then when //activity destroys then it will become null. So you got the null pointer exception.


public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static MyApplication myApplication = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        myApplication = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return myApplication;
    }

}

//Your method looks like this
public static int getColor(int resID) {
        return MyApplication.getInstance().getResources().getColor(resID);
    }
```